# Error calling Process.Start("mailto:...")

Tags: c#, email, exception, mailto, process.start

hello i send a email with this code

```
Process.Start("mailto:" + Email + "?subject=Contact" + "&body=" + bodymesssage);
```

in my pc work correctly , but in the server throw this error in the client side :

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

this is a configuration missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this in an ASP.NET app on a server?  That's not how you send e-mail on a server.

Comment: How long is the 'bodymessage' variable?

Comment: Yes its a configuration issue as ALPESH mentions in his answer, no point in parroting what he says, when you can read it in the link below with context to what others say and tried to resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead:

```
public static void SendMessage(String server, String[] emails, String subject, String body)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(m_Sender, String.Join(",", emails), subject, body);

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    try { client.Send(message); }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("ERROR!"); }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation? Just a piece of code is not that useful.

Comment: Well there are no really explainations. This code snippet just uses managed classes integrated into .NET Framework to do exacly what you were trying to do, but without using external commands (which I always prefer). It's easier to catch inputs, it's easier to produce readable output, it's easier to debug. Plus, this supports Attachments while "mailto" doesn't. For further knowlegde I suggest you to read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx